# What does compiling permutation mean in GWT?

Tags: gwt, compiler-construction

When a Web App Project is compiled, 6 permutations are compiled. What are those permutations, and what do they mean?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Google Web Toolkit uses deferred binding; it creates different versions of your application for different browser targets and localizations.  Their FAQ response on [Deferred Binding](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_DeferredBindingDefinition) goes into more detail, but basically can be summed up in this quote:

> For instance, if GWT supports 4 browsers, and you write your application in 3 languages, then GWT will generate a total of 12 different permutations of your application. During bootstrapping at runtime, GWT picks the appropriate permutation to show the user.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to temporarily remove some browser models and languages to shorten compilation times during development.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the user agent and specify your browser in your *.gwt.xml (x5 compile if you use a specific browser)

For firefox only use: `<set-property name="user.agent" value="gecko1_8" />`

More info [@topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890352/gwt-module-xml-how-to-redefine-and-use-more-than-one-user-agent)

Answer (score 1):

Skipping permutations is only useful for testing purposes. In example, I'm configuring maven assembly plugin, so skipping them allows me to do configuration tests with assembly MUCH more faster.